# jQuery - set a timeout to 3 secs and then run a function

Tags: jquery

Is there a way with jQuery - to set a timeout to 3 secs and then run a function without needing a timer plugin?

Comment: i vote to close, because I feel this has to be a doppelganger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could [use a `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). This doesn't require jQuery.

```
function myfunc() {
   alert('run');
}

setTimeout( myfunc, 3000 ); // call "myfunc" after 3 seconds
```

Will need more info if this isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks , I have used your solution

Answer (score 5):

"Is there a way with jQuery"? Sure! for jQuery 1.4 and higher, you can use [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) like:

```
$("someElement").doSomething().delay(3000).doSomethingElse();
```

Otherwise without the jQuery lib you can use `setTimeOut(doSomething(), milliseconds)` as suggested by my peers.

Answer (score 2):

Just use native JavaScript: [setTimeout()](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)